# How does the authentication works in Jhipster lite

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

Hi I'm new to the Jhipster lite, I have generated a microservice with Jwt authentication and I am also running the Jhipster registry. I used the default username and password  `admin/admin` to generate the token when I used the token to access the endpoint it keeps throwing `c.m.m.a.i.primary.JwtReader: Invalid JWT token` in the console and a `403 Forbidden` in the postman. Is there any additional configuration needed?